# Reading and maintaining a stack of input streams

Tags: c++, stack, ifstream

So I'm trying to create a loop that reads lines through a file and do stuff based on the line, except that some lines can be another file name which I need to open and start reading from that file, while keeping the original file on a stack, this can happen multiple times and when a new file is EOF, I need to pop back the previous file from the stack.

```
    std::ifstream* currentStream = fileStream;
    // this is within a class where I pass through fileStream in its initialization
    stack<std::ifstream*> fileStack = stack<std::ifstream*>();

    while(!fileStack.empty() || !currentStream->eof()){
      while (!currentStream->eof()) {
        getline(*currentStream, lineBuf);
        string line = trim(lineBuf);  
        if (line = blahblah) {
          //do stuff
        }
        else if (words[0] == "file") {
          auto params = extractParameters(line);
          std::ifstream simpFileStream;
          simpFileStream.open(params[1][0].substr(1, params[1][0].length()-2) + ".simp");
          currentStream->swap(simpFileStream);
          fileStack.push(&simpFileStream);
        }
        if(!fileStack.empty() && currentStream->eof()){
          // what to do here?
          fileStack.pop();
        }
      }
    }
```

In my code I've tried a couple ways, but this is what I have last saved, I basically create a new ifstream and swap the current one and attempt to push the old one on the stack, I'm not sure if that's even working properly.

In my if statement, I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work so that's where I am having trouble. Basically when I test my code, opening a new stream works and it starts reading into the new files, but I'm not entirely sure how to pop back into the old ifstream.

Comment: you may use a recursive function having a file name as its argument. in the function, you open the file and read in lines. when read in a file name, call the function with the file name.

Comment: You are doing almost everything wrong. You are looping on `eof`. You are pushing the address of streams that go out of scope onto your stack. You are reusing moved from file streams... It is also very unclear what the programs is supposed to be doing so it's hard to make suggestions.

Comment: you're right, i made a bunch of changes and deleted things in attempt to make it work properly. i guess my real question is whether there is a way to properly save a filestream onto a stack to pop back later on.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to be more succinct then. I was trying to follow your logic but was unable to see what you are trying to do. After you push a new file stream onto the stack you immediately take it off again...?

Comment: I apologize for the messy question. The part where it pops from the stack is meant to be if the file is empty and I want to get the previous file from the top of the stack and then pop it off the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me from your comments that ou may be looking for a structure something a bit like this:

```
void method(std::string const& filename)
{
    // use smart pointers to avoid memory leaks
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>> files;

    // open initial file and push it to the top of the stack
    // to use as the 'current' file
    files.push(std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(filename));

    // use the top() of the stack as your 'current' file stream

    // as long as we have open files, keep going
    while(!files.empty())
    {
        // read the line in the loop control block
        for(std::string line; std::getline(*files.top(), line);)
        {
            if(line == "some stuff")
            {
                // start a new file on the top of the stack
                files.push(std::make_unique<std::ifstream>("new file name"));
            }
            else if(line == "some other stuff")
            {
                // do other stuff
            }
            // yet more stuff
        }

        // end of file reached here - pop
        // delete the current file stream off the top
        // of the stack (automatically closing the file)
        files.pop();
        // Now the top of the stack contains the previous current file stream
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the structure is exactly what I was looking for.